# Disable link on mobile device

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have a page that is being populated by Content View Plugin. The content are blog posts of a particular category. I have disabled links so that people only see the content on that page, and cannot click on the thumbnail to go to the post page. I disabled clicks with CSS, however, on mobile devices this does not work. As in, if I touch the thumbnail, it still takes me to the post page. Not sure if I made sense; here's the page for reference:

http://studio.usualhabitat.com/portfolio/

here's what I am using:

```
body.page-id-686 img.pt-cv-thumbnail {touch-action: none!important; pointer-events: none!important; cursor: default!important;}
body.page-id-686 .pt-cv-ifield a._self {touch-action: none!important; pointer-events: none!important; cursor: default!important;}
```

Comment: Post your code here so we can help.

Comment: I edited the post :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use touch-action: none;

Regards.